# Android Variables not updating in Notification

Tags: android, mobile

I'm  using some alarm functions to produce a notification every five seconds. In the functions there are variables which should change  each time it is called. But nothing is happening , it just continues to display the first set of data in the notification.
This is from the MainActivity class:

```
public void setRepeatingAlarm(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, TimeAlarm.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), (5 * 1000), pendingIntent);      
}
```

This is from the TimeAlarm class:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    CharSequence from = "Homework";
    CharSequence message = "test"+ MainActivity.arraytest[x2]+ x2;
    x2 +=1;
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,new Intent(context,TimeAlarm.class), 0);
    Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"Update", System.currentTimeMillis());
    notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, from, message, contentIntent);
    nm.notify(notify_id, notif);
}
```

The problem is that the x2 variable is not updating. it only updates when it is first called.
Thanks.

Comment: I don't know why you are using notifications every 5 seconds but it's a poor design choice. I'd personally uninstall any app that sent notifications every 5 seconds.

Comment: where is the variable x2 declared? I guess that it's a private field on TimeAlarm? If so it is going to be reinitialised on every alarm. In which case make it static. Otherwise post all/more of the TimeAlarm class

Comment: Making the x2 variable static seemed to do the trick thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making the x2 variable static seemed to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe long shot but... I suspect that `x2` may be accessed by more than one threads? In that case, it should be declared as `volatile` in order for compiler to skip any optimizations not suitable for variables accessed by multiple threads (which can be causing the wrong behaviour in this case).

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing anything else with `x2`? Have a look at the lifecycle documentation for [BroadcastReciever.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#ReceiverLifecycle) Likely your instance of `TimeAlarm` is getting killed after each run of `onReceive()`; you'll need to do something to persist the value of `x2` between runs.

Comment: I'm not doing anything else with x2

Comment: Could it be to do with the "arraytest" being static?

Comment: Each time `onRecieve()` finishes running, Android kills the instance of that class. You'll need to persist the value of `x2` somehow (to a flat file or database, for example), then reload it on each run of `onRecieve()`.